# tmux not working with 'send-prefix' for inner session

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I am using `tmux` and I am setting some settings to handle nested sessions. I like to have a local tmux session, as well as a tmux session on servers I SSH into.

To do that, I added `bind-key -n C-\ send-prefix` in the configuration file to intercept `C-\` to be passed into the inner session.

When I hit C-\, it is not caught. But when I replace `\` with a letter, such as `b`, to have `C-b`, it works.

Which means that what I'm doing is right, but it is not recognizing the `\` character. Do I need to escape it? If so, how? `C-\\` does not work.

**EDIT**

So apparently `C-b` works not because of my binding but because thats the default binding for tmux. I forgot to source the config file. But when I do, the key just gives me a new line. Is there anything I need to do in the configuration file of the inner tmux session?

Comment: I found the answer found at Superuser:

http://superuser.com/questions/417236/tmux-with-non-alphanumeric-prefix

Comment: In the future, superuser.com is the appropriate place to post this sort of question. Good luck.

Comment: @Darksky, you can make your edit an Answer and accept it. (You could also link to the superuser post that helped you.) I'm going to flag this to be moved to SU.